# Classification Benchmarks

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, supervised-learning

Is there a list of benchmarks for state-of-the-art ML classification algorithms (e.g. not sklearn's) that isn't for MNIST or images, but for a vector of features? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, UCI has a pretty sizable collection of data sets that I have seen used in many papers. There is some overlap with sklearn's internal data sets as well though.

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

There is also Kaggle. I believe that most of these datasets are originating from their competitions.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets